# Load Table But another response is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 with csrf active.

I have tried to make Search form with the table will load without loading on page.
It is success on first attempt, but another response--which is `token_value` get undefined. And if I tried to search for the second time it get error 403 Forbidden.

Here is my jquery looks like:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){

    $.post("vendor/search",
    {
      "searchByCode":$("input[name='searchByCode']").val(),
      "<?= csrf_token() ?>" : "<?= csrf_hash() ?>"
    },
     function(data, status){
      alert(data.token_value);
      $("#table_vendors").html(data);
    });

});
```

and this is my related Controller looks like

```
    public function search()
    {

        $result = $this->vendors;

        if ($this->request->getPost('searchByCode')) {
            $result->like('code', $this->request->getPost('searchByCode'));
        };

        $data = [
            'vendors' => $result->paginate(10, 'vendors'),
            'page' => $result->pager,
            'token_value' => csrf_hash()
        ];

        return view('vendors/_vendors', $data);
    }
```

This is what happen when I click search for a second time.
[image]

I wish I could do re-search with my code above without refreshing page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your JS:

```
// Courtesy of W3Schools :o)
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function resetCSRF(){
    $('input[name="csrf_cookie_name"]').val(getCookie('csrf_cookie_name'));
}
```

Assuming your cookie name is csrf_cookie_name then call `resetCSRF()` after each form submit. This code will get the latest Cookie value and set it in the form and should allow you to resubmit without refreshing.